# Image corrupted when loading offline with com.squareup.okhttp3

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I get an dogear in every image loaded when phone is offline using com.squareup.okhttp3

The image loaded from firebase is the right image, but there is some eardog on it...

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0-alpha02'

ImageView UserPostParty = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            Picasso.get().load(party).fit().into(UserPostParty);[image]

Answer (score 0):

.setIndicatorsEnabled(false); should be set!!!